# Insert Multiple Records in ASP.NET DynamicData Applicatoin

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using ASP.NET DynamicData v4.5 to allow admin to insert/update the records in the database.

My requirement is,
-- Allow admin to insert more than one record at a time. By default, if Admin wants to insert 10 records he need to insert it one by one.
-- I tried updating the Default_Insert.ascx page to display 10 rows. It displays 10 rows, but saving only one record.

How can i acheive my requirement

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code to get a better idea of your issue

Comment: Need more details to understand you are  requirement..

Comment: @HarveySpecter By default Dynamic Data allows Insert one record in a single go for each entity using Page Default_Insert.ascx. 

But how can i acheive multiple record insert in single go ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure. in which you pass the arrays of values. and inside stored procedure you can insert them into dsatabase one by one. When admin will insert 10 records, he has to pass all 10 records in stored procedure. He will hit stored procedure only once and all records will be updated in database.

Comment: Yes. If you post your code here. I can explain better.